# How to use finishActivityFromChild() and finishFromChild() in android to have more control on activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I am just trying to end the Activity that was started before two or more activities, like based on a condition from **'N'** th Child, not the immediate child activity,i want to remove activity from stack,
I dont want to pass on information through all the child classes and get result by **startActivityForResult()**,
so will I be able to use **finishActivityFromChild()** or **finishFromChild()** to achieve this ?
If not at least explain me why are these method used in android with good example since i don't see many people using this function anywhere.